# jQuery Finds Elements Position Before Repositioned in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to get repositioned elements to animate when the page scrolls down and they become visible. My problem is that jQuery is using the first (before being positioned) position to trigger an animation, but the element is higher up on the page so when I scroll, I see the element and continue scrolling a little then the animation is triggered. **How can I make the jQuery find the re-positioned position and use that to animate instead of position before the element was positioned?** Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {

    /**
     * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
     * Licensed under the MIT license.
     * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
     *
     * @author Sam Sehnert
     * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
     *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
     *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
     */

    $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t = $(this),
        $w = $(window),
        viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

      return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

    };

  })(jQuery);

  var win = $(window);

  var allMods = $(".animated");

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("already-visible");
    }
  });

  win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("come-in");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
/* Slide In */

* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
.animated {} .come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
/* Positioned Elements */

/* About */

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 145px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 360px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 160px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 170px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 180px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 130px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 140px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .container2 {
    top: 155px;
  }
}
#about {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  p {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
#aboutbar {
  background-color: #151413;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #aboutbar {
    background-color: #151413;
    height: 5px;
    width: 56.6666666667%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
/* Managers */

/* 278 PX */

#managersbg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 495px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 288px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 495px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 295px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 455px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 358px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 364px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 416px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 485px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 624px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 450px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 671px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 914px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500
}
#managers {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
#screamer,
#swezii,
#kinzu {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#screamer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#swezii {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
}
#kinzu {
  position: relative;
  top: 275px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  position: relative;
}
#manager1 {
  top: -115px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  font-weight: 600
}
#manager2 {
  top: 45px;
}
#manager3 {
  top: 195px;
}
#text1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -165px;
}
#text2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #text1,
  #text2,
  #text3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
    text-align: center;
  }
}
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <p>TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We were founded in the winter of 2014. We connect clients to the designers they need. Our goal is to serve high quality design at an affordable price through the internet. We strive to impress our clients.
      We don't sell graphics, or designs. We sell art and colours.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="animated">
  <div class="seven columns" id="aboutbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="managersbg">
  <div class="container3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated">
        <h4 id="managers">Our Managers</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column" id="screamer">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column" id="swezii">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column" id="kinzu">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column">
          <p id="manager1">Screamer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column">
          <p id="manager2">Swezii</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="one-third-column">
          <p id="manager3">KINZU</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="seven columns">
          <p id="text1">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="seven columns">
          <p id="text2">I love the fliudity of art, of any kind!. It is my goal to become a bettter designer myself so I can share my knowldge with others. I am one of the best designers for my price.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="seven columns">
          <p id="text3">I'm that guy chilling on his computer, creating fantastic art for you. You can bet you'll get what you ask for!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What is `.animated {}` ?

Comment: It's a class with nothing in it. It's like a placeholder.

Comment: What is the animation ?

Comment: Anything with a class of animated should slide in from the bottom of the page as the page is scrolled (This is triggered by the jQuery)

Comment: Can describe "slide in from the bottom of the page" ?

Comment: Just before the element becomes visible it slides up into view.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in jsFiddle so we can check it out?

Comment: No, I don't know what that is. Do you really need to see it, you have the code... I need to know if I can do something to the jQuery file so it finds the repositioned location of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to call the reposition function after the scroll animation has ended.

Here's a little trick that I use for detecting the end of an animation and then triggering a bit of JQuery / Javascript after its has done.

```
  doSomeFunction: function() {
     //do something now animation has ended
  },
  slideOut: function() {
    var elem = $('div.message-text');

    // set up some function to call - 'this' will be the events 'this' 
    // so take a reference to this used here
    var self = this;
    var func = function() {
      self.doSomeFunction();
    };

    // Set up what happens when the animation ends - will run ONE time only
    elem.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', func);

    // Add Animation now
    elem.addClass('fadeInLeft');
  },
```

Comment: No I want it to be repositioned

Comment: Hit send prematurely: No I want it to be repositioned before then I want the jQuery to find the new position then trigger the animation using that position. Because right now it seems as the jQuery is loading before the css then it uses the original position which makes the animation trigger when I scroll down the page more than I should have because the css moved it. Basically